# Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media .Net SDK failing to get/find asset by name

Tags: azure-media-services

I'm trying to get an Asset by name using the v3 api for Azure Media Services.  Both GetAsync and ListAsync w/ODataQuery fail to locate the item, however, paging through all the assets using ListAsync and ListNextAsync will eventually find it.  This is in a mediaservices account with 30-40 thousand assets.  I'm looking for ideas/suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm moving to the v3 API since this is a dotnet core app, and the v2 API seems to be stuck at framework 4.5.  A sample program can be found below.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.OData;

namespace MediaServicesTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var arm_endpoint = "https://management.azure.com";
            var credentials = new ClientCredential("xxxxx", "yyyyy");
            var token = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync("aaaaa", credentials, ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure);

            IAzureMediaServicesClient client = new AzureMediaServicesClient(new Uri(arm_endpoint), token)
            {
                SubscriptionId = "sssss",
            };
            var resourceGroupName = "zzzzz";
            var accountName = "bbbbb";
            try
            {
                var name = "b98b7c8f-4ee3-42c5-b0bd-d1cb08a3776c";
        // neither of these queries work
                var cdataQuery = new ODataQuery<Asset>(a => a.Name == name);
                /*
                var cdataQuery = new ODataQuery<Asset>()
                {
                    Filter = $"name eq '{name}'"
                };
                */
                var assets = await client.Assets.ListAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, cdataQuery, CancellationToken.None);
                if (assets.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Found Asset with name={name} using ListAsync with Query");
                }

        // neither does this
                if (await client.Assets.GetAsync(
                    resourceGroupName, 
                    accountName, 
                    name, 
                    CancellationToken.None) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Found Asset with name={name} using GetAsync");
                }

        // this works but is gross and inefficient
                assets = await client.Assets.ListAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, null, CancellationToken.None);
                var i = 0;
                while(assets.All(x => x.Name != name) && assets.NextPageLink != null)
                {
                    assets = await client.Assets.ListNextAsync(assets.NextPageLink, CancellationToken.None);
                }

                var asset = assets.FirstOrDefault();
                if (asset != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Found Asset with name={name} iterating over ListAsync");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After carefully reading the documentation, I think the query problem of 30-40 thousand assets you mentioned should not exist. If you still have questions, you can use the [RESP API] (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-rest-postman) to test. The parts of your code that need to be modified in the post have all helped you. The modification is complete.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? I personally think that the current version of Media Services is V3, and there should be no bugs you said. I suggest you read the official documents carefully and study the source code. If the problem still exists, it should not be a problem with the code. It is recommended that you raise a support ticket in Azure Portal. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: No the issue is not resolved, I'm working with Microsoft's technical support and product teams and once I have a resolution I will post it.  The docs you pointed out are the ones I followed initially.  You can't change the page size for Assets. The AMS Explorer source code while helpful also demonstrate the same problem.  Once I have a resolution worked out with Microsoft I will update this thread.